# Create a deny role attribute in .netcore 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-5.0, authorize-attribute

I want to create an attribute based on the authorize attribute that instead of granting a role access to an IActionResult it denies access.

I want to decorate the ActionResult with something like `[Deny(Role="role")]` so that if the role tries to access this it is redirected back to the refering url.

I have tried to modify the code below but a lot of the methods used do not exist in .netcore 5.0:

```
public class DenyAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return !base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class DenyByControllerActionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var controller = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var action = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var denyRole = string.Format("Deny{0}:{1}", controller, action);
        return !httpContext.User.IsInRole(denyRole) && base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

How would go about creating something like the above code examples in .netcore 5.0 since the AuthorizeCore override no longer exist in .net 5.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, you need implements `Attribute` and `IAuthorizationFilter` to custom authorize attribute:

```
public class DenyAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public string? Roles { get; set; }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var originalUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
        var userInRole = context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(Roles);
        if(userInRole)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult(originalUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Deny(Roles = "yourRole")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View();
}
```